# Index a matrix based on another matrix's values

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a matrix (really, a 3-D array) that I would like to "threshold" based on the values in another matrix (which is completely binarized). So, e.g.

```
set.seed(1234)
M <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3, byrow=F)
M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
set.seed(1234)
N <- matrix(sample(c(0, 0, 1), 9, replace=T), nrow=3)
N
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

I would like to keep only the values in `M` that are in the same location as where `N` equals 1; turn the rest into 0's. Output should be:

```
M.thresh
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    5    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

Comment: I've added the `set.seed` function for reproducibility. Fix your desired output to those new (and always the same) matrices.

Comment: `M.thresh <- ifelse(N!=1,0,M)`

Comment: @Heroka I think I need an extra dose of coffee... that was a painfully obvious solution. Thanks!

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not as comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace with matrix indexing.

```
N[N == 1] <- M[N == 1]
N
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    5    0
# [3,]    0    0    0
```

Or `replace(N, N == 1, M[N == 1])`